# animating :after pseudo element does not work

Tags: css

I am new to coding, I have tried various solutions from similar questions asked, but nothing seems to work.

I have the following problem:

I made a breadcrumb, including various divs with :before and :after elements - shaping them like connected arrows.
The problem is, I made an animation for the breadcrumb element to fade-in-down. However, no matter in what combination I tried -> The :after element does not animate properly, or at all.

It kinda just pops up after :before and the parent div .breadcrumb have finished sliding in. Can anybody help me here, or has anyone maybe have aa clue?

... I have tried animating the :after element separatly, with transition, with animation-delay etc...nothing seems to work...everything slides in fine from top, excep the :after element, which just pops up ugly after the animation from my ".breadcrumb" is finished.

```
<div class="breadcrumb_wrapper">
<a href="../index.html" class="breadcrumb_element"></a>
<a href="#" class="breadcrumb_element active fade-in-down-wrapper">Lasermaschinen</a>
<a href="#" class="breadcrumb_element">Serien</a>
<a href="#" class="breadcrumb_element">Unterserien</a>
<a href="#" class="breadcrumb_element">Produkt</a>
```

```
.breadcrumb_wrapper {
position: fixed;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-top: 120px;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.breadcrumb_element {
padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
width: auto;
line-height: 32px;
min-height: 32px;
max-height: 32px;
background: var(--Breadcrumb-gradient);
position: relative;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 0.5rem;
color: var(--nav-text-color-and-general-background);
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
animation: fade-in-down 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

}

```
.breadcrumb_element:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 4.69px;
left: -11.32px;
width: 22.427px;
height: 22.427px;
background: var(--nav-text-color-and-general-background);
transform: rotate(45deg);
z-index: 1;
border-top: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
border-right: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
```

}

```
.breadcrumb_element:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 4.69px;
right: -11.6px;
width: 22.427px;
height: 22.427px;
background: var(--Breadcrumb-arrow-gradient);
transform: rotate(45deg);
z-index: 2;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
animation: fade-in-down 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

}

```
@keyframes fade-in-down {
0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
100% {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

}

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML code I just had to take a guess at how you need this but here is an example with the after pseudo element coming in from the top and sitting on top of the before pseudo. Hope this helps you get what you are looking for. You can have it come in from any direction that you want.

```css
ul { 
list-style: none;
display: flex;
overflow: hidden;
}

li { 
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
position: relative;
}

li::before { 
content: '';
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
right: -25px;
}

li::after {
content: '';
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
right: -25px;
top: -100px;
transition: all 1s;
}

li:hover:after {
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Menu Item 1</li>
<li>Menu Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added the html and the .wrapper css.

I tried it with transition on the :after element, though it does not do anything, like everything else I have tried...I don't know why...

I haven't constructed it as an ul/li - does that make a difference?

Comment: No it shouldn't matter at all whether you use a ul or not

Comment: Then I don't know...

Comment: Try this fiddle and let me know if its close https://jsfiddle.net/baq61u0o/1/

Comment: I tried around, though I'm getting crazy for hours now...thank you very much for you support! For some reaason, whatever I try (also your opacity solution), it doesn't work out...and I just dont get it...

I have uploaded the whole breadcrumb here, that will show what makes me crazy, see the :after "arrow" that kinda just pops up after the animation?
I figured it seems to be overlapped be the :before element...but I can't get ir working right...

here'the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Alex414141/ghm9axvb/